# Swift 4 json decode with top level array

Tags: json, swift

While getting JSON data from my API, I can't get it to decode properly.

```
[ 
{ 
"success": "true",
 "message": "testtt" 
} 
]
```

This is what my API output looks like.

As we can see, my PHP outputs the values as an top level array.

How can I read out this information in Swift 4?

```
let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([API].self, from: data)
```

returns:

> success: "true", message: "testtt"

This is what the struct looks like:

```
struct API: Decodable{
    let success: String
    let message: String

    init(jsont: [String: Any]){
        success = jsont["success"] as? String ?? ""
        message = jsont["message"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

But then I don't know how to read out this data further.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does this mean **i dont know how to read out this data further**

Comment: What do you mean? Does the call to `Decode` fail? If so, what error is thrown. If it works, then `json` will be an array of `API` with one element and you have your data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to creat a custom initialiser. You just use the Array type  `[API].self` when decoding your json:

```
struct API: Decodable{
    let success: String
    let message: String
}
```

---

```
let dataJSON = Data("""
[
    {
        "success": "true",
        "message": "testtt"
    }
]
""".utf8)
```

---

```
do {
    if let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([API].self, from: dataJSON).first {
        print(result.success)
        print(result.message)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: note op actually do this **let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([API].self, from: data)**

Comment: What is the difference? If OP can't realise that he needs to change my sample `dataJSON` with the `data` object returned by his server I wouldn't even try to help him further

Comment: the op may misunderstands something , as what in your answer the op seems to successfully did

Comment: @Sh_Khan well that info was not there when I first answer this question. As it is right now it is even more unclear than before.

Comment: Btw looks like his API should be returning `"success": true` instead of `"success": "true"` and he should declare success property as Bool type

Comment: Thank you, the .first at the end of the let result rule was what i was looking for, now result.success and result.message are recognized. I will also change the api to output a bool in stead of an string.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access make one more struct like

```
struct data: Decodable{
let API: [API]
}
```

Then in your program you must decode like below above

```
let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(data.self, from: data)
```

and access to them

```
data.API[i].success
data.API[i].message
```