# How to decode JSON Array with no key in Swift

Tags: json, swift, api, decoding

I'm kinda new to Swift so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious here. I am using an API that returns a JSON in this format:

```
[
    {
        "title" : String
        "image" : [
                {
                    "is_leader": Bool
                    "urlPath": String
                }
              ],
        "body": String
    },
    {
        "title" : String
        "image" : [
                {
                    "is_leader": Bool
                    "urlPath": String
                }
        ]
        "body": String
    },
]
```

And I cant seem to decode it.

Here are my models:

```
struct ArticleData: Decodable {
    let Articles: [Article]?

}

struct Article: Decodable {
    let title: String?
    let images: [Images]?
    let body: String?
}
```

```
struct Images: Decodable {
    let images: [Image]?
}

struct Image: Decodable {
    let isLeader: Bool?
    let url: String?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case url, width, height
        case isLeader = "is_Leader"
    }
}
```

And this is the decoder method that I am using

```
   do {
       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
       let jsonData = try decoder.decode([ArticleData.self], from: data)
```

When I run this I am just getting a nil response and I'm just im not really sure why. I am for sure hitting the API

All help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: That’s not a valid JSON you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to change from `try decoder.decode([ArticleData.self], from: data)` to `try decoder.decode([Article].self, from: data)`.

Duplicate of [Swift 4 json decode with top level array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085720/swift-4-json-decode-with-top-level-array)